# How to get the source of a javascript bookmark from itself when running?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a bookmark that's a JavaScript bookmark. For example:

```js
javascript:alert('hi');
```

I'd like to be able to get the source of the currently running JavaScript bookmark, from within the bookmark itself, so in pseudocode:

```js
javascript:alert(currentlyExecutingScript.text);
```

Which would alert

```js
javascript:alert(currentlyExecutingScript.text);
```

How can I do this? I prefer cross browser solutions, but am completely fine with just Chrome specific solutions!

Why am I interested in this? Because I'm writing a bookmarklet that refers to itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `location` refers to the current page's URL, and JavaScript bookmarks do not change `location`, this is not possible in any current browsers.

However, it *is* possible to do what you want in JavaScript:

```js
javascript:void function f(){alert(f.toString())}()
```

That will `alert` the following:

```js
function f(){alert(f.toString())}
```

The `toString()` method, when called on a function, returns a string representing the source code of the function (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString).

### Credit

[@SergeSeredenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805519/serge-seredenko) suggested to use `void`.

> When using an immediately-invoked function expression, `void` can be used to force the function keyword to be treated as an expression instead of a declaration.
>   — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#Immediately_Invoked_Function_Expressions

Comment: I'd anonymize it to not mess with window: `void function f(){alert(f+'')}()`

Comment: @SergeSeredenko I edited my answer earlier, and credited you. However, it's not actually necessary to use `void`. A function declaration does not change the global scope ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)).

Comment: What do you mean? You can use `(function f()})()` or `void`. Without both, like `function f(){};f()`, f will go global. Test it if you wish.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Test it and you'll see. Bookmarklet affects global scope.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Yeah, you're right. I don't know what happened; I must have got two tabs confused when I tested it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your script in a string, and an evil `eval` to execute it, with the script having a reference to itself :

```
javascript:var script = "alert('hi'); alert(script)";
eval(script);
```

It'll alert "hi", and then the content of `script`.

Comment: Yep, but that EvilEval© isn't that evil in that case, am I right?

Comment: Yeah. However, my method should be Slightly Faster™ (not that anyone would notice), and safer (at least according to JavaScript Sense™).

Comment: @toothbrush Agreed yours is more... elegant :) Here, have a kudo !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, though definetely **not** the safest, way of achieving this is by storing your code in a string, and evaluating that string when you click the bookmark.

```
var code = "alert('Hi');var num = 988;alert(num + 12)";
//code contains the code you wish to run
eval(code);
//runs the code.
alert(code); 
//alerts the code.
```

I would be very careful with the use of the `eval()` function.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) for more information.

Comment: Why do you say *definetely not the safest*? I don't see any risk related to `eval` here.

Comment: Depending on implementation, someone could modify the `code` variable too run what ever malicious code they want.